# Windows 8.1 upgrade does not work

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

After doing a complete re-install, I finally have Windows 8.1 from the Windows 8 store. (The other options (the KB fix, the clear store cache, etc.) never worked.)

When I click it, it says that I need to be an administrator. I am an administrator. How do I upgrade to Windows 8.1?

Comment: Have you tried right clicking and selecting the option to "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: after hours on with dell support then transferred to microsoft support, they downloaded an exe from a website or something and avoided the store completely(ie. microsoft couldn't figure it out).